# How can I render mat-table by button I defined?

Tags: angular-material, angular6, angular5

I have mat-table and select button above mat-table. Once I click select butotn, I am pulling datas from web API and I want data to be viewed in table. But clever!! Angular team does not support this or not documented.  Very classical things are not supported in angular-Material components.

Let me ask question:

**.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
            (click)="list()">
          Select
</button>


<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource1" class="mat-elevation-z8">
......
</mat-table>
```

**.ts**

```
list() {

    dataSource1 = .....

}
```

How can I provide this ?  Table is not rendered after datas are successfully assigned to dataSource1 in list() method. What should I do to rerender

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417522/how-to-pass-data-to-material-table-data-source-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

you should use `renderRows` method of `MatTable`.

https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTable

**.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="list()">
      Select
</button>


<mat-table #myTable [dataSource]="dataSource1" class="mat-elevation-z8">
     ......
</mat-table>
```

**.ts**

```
@ViewChild("myTable") myTable:MatTable;

list() {

    dataSource1 = .....
    myTable.renderRows();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot and after searching for 10 hours , I realized that I had applied Angular material 7.x  component and after changing the sample for material 5.2.5 , It worked for me